# How safe is it to cache dependencies built from source in Travis CI

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, virtualenv, travis-ci

This question regards the caching capabilities of Travis CI.

My project ([quamash](http://github.com/harvimt/quamash)) has some pretty weird dependencies. It needs to be tested 6 times once with PySide, once with PyQt4 and once with PyQt5 on Python 3.3 and Python 3.4 to really test all the code. (I also need to test on a *nix platform and a windows platform, since each use different asyncio backends, but that's not really relevant.).

PySide is easy because it can be installed with pip. I just have pre-built wheels (they're being kept on github now, but they don't need to be, might be cleaner to not)

I can get binary packages for Qt4 (from precise) and Qt5 (from a ppa). The PyQt4 (python3-qt4) package that comes precise is for python 3.2 so it's worthless. And PyQt5 is totally unavailable.

Installing a global package and then using it is hard anyway.

PyQt4/5 have a common dependency in SIP which is a Python binding generator for C++. (all 3 are developed by riverbank computing)

With just PySide my tests finish in under a minute, but PyQt takes ~5minutes to build (times 2 for both versions). I suppose a ~10 minute build isn't that bad, but it just seems like a waste since it's mostly being spent on dependencies.

Can I safely cache the PyQt & SIP build directories and then just run `sudo make install` from them every time? Should I build a .deb file (can I? and then install to a virtualenv?)

Answer (score 0):

I think we'd all benefit if you created a PPA with PyQt5 backported to Ubuntu 12.04.

I think so, because I came here looking for PyQt5 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Here's a relevant question on [how to create PPA in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa).

Comment: I don't think this will work for me. They need to be installed into travis's venv. I probably need a way to build wheels.